# list with checkboxes alter style of checked text

Tags: html, css

So here is the problem. I want a list. It has to be a list not a form with label and input and when it's checked the text should be crossed.

Here is what I have but the CSS for the line-through if checked doesn't work:

```css
li input:checked  {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="todo"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" id="todo">Setup todo List
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should place the text inside the label, and the label after the input.

```css
li > input:checked + label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" id="todo">
    <label for="todo">Setup todo List</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```